# Serialize Pojos to JSON using new standard javax.json

Tags: java, json, java-ee-7

I like the idea of having a standard for JSON serialization in Java, javax.json is a great step forward you can do an object graph like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject3 =
Json.createObjectBuilder()
.add("name", "Ersin")
.add("surname", "Çetinkaya")
.add("age", 25)
.add("address",
      Json.createObjectBuilder()
          .add("city", "Bursa")
          .add("country", "Türkiye")
          .add("zipCode", "33444"))
.add("phones",
              Json.createArrayBuilder()
                  .add("234234242")
                  .add("345345354"))
.build();
```

That's it, but how can I serialize a pojo or  simple Java object(like a Map) direct to JSON?, something like I do in Gson:

```
Person person = new Person();
String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(person);
```

How can I do this with the new standard API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Java API for JSON Processing** ([JSR-353](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353)) does not cover object binding.  This will be covered in a separate JSR.

Comment: Will that JSR be delivered in Java EE7?

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli - No, it is not part of Java EE 7 which is already release.

Comment: It's such a pity, Well I will be using Gson, It would be useful to make Gson a JSR

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli - Hopefully there will be news of the JSON-Binding JSR soon.  I will announce it on my "Java XML and JSON Binding" blog (http://blog.bdoughan.com/) as soon as the JSR starts up.

Answer (score 7):

See JSR-367, Java API for JSON Binding (JSON-B), a headline feature in Java™ EE 8.

Document: [Json Binding 1.0 Users Guide](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/users-guide.html)

```
// Create Jsonb and serialize
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
String result = jsonb.toJson(dog);

// Deserialize back
dog = jsonb.fromJson("{name:\"Falco\", age:4, bitable:false}", Dog.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because this question is almost 5 years old (I didn't check which java release has these classes) but there is a standard way with `javax.json.*` classes:

```
JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("key", "value")
        .build();
try(JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(outputStream)) {
    writer.write(json);
}
```